# Scalajs, js.Dictionary inconsistent behavior

Tags: javascript, scala, scala.js

I have an inconsistent error using ScalaJS. Here is a minimal example: the size and the content of a dictionary variable are inconsistent.

```
def A(mapping: js.Dictionary[String]): Unit = {
  dom.console.log(mapping)
  dom.console.log(mapping.size)
}
```

I link the IRs using fastOptJS. In the driver code in html, I have

```
const colorSetting = new Map([
        ["1", "black"]
]);
ScalaJSExample.A(colorSetting)
```

In the console, the first line prints the content of the variable correctly,

```
"Map {"1" => "black"}"
```

but the second line prints 0. I have also tried to swap the position of the two lines, but the result is the same. Any methods such as .foreach or the for (x <- mapping) all treat the variable mapping as empty.

Any suggestion why this is the case? I am using Scala 2.12.8, ScalaJS 1.7.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `js.Dictionary` represents a POJO (plain old JavaScript object) where elements are fields. But you are passing a JS `new Map()` to it, which is not a POJO--it's a `Map`. The correct type to represent a JS Map is `js.Map`.

Either pass a dictionary to `ScalaJSExample.A`, as follows:

```js
const colorSetting = {
    "1": "black"
};
ScalaJSExample.A(colorSetting)
```

or declare `mapping` as a `js.Map` in the Scala.js code:

```
def A(mapping: js.Map[String, String]): Unit = {
  dom.console.log(mapping)
  dom.console.log(mapping.size)
}
```